# Modify Resource.resx file at runtime manually

Tags: c#, resources, resx

I have been asked to make a resx file available for updating/modifying at runtime, this should be done manually though, not programatically. So the file will be in the installation folder, and then they would go there to update values. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

(Almost) anything is possible.  You can use the  [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) so when someone changes any values in the file, your program will see that, and you just proceed to re-load the new values.